# How to get items after something in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am using textblob to  parse the text in english. Here is a list of words.

```
['Get', 'coffee', 'and', 'water', 'here']
```

1. I want to get all the words after the item 'Get' in a new list called list1.
2. I want to get all the words between  'Get' and 'here' in a new list called list2.

What would be the best way to do that? Are there any prebuilt functions for doing it as I want to keep my script clean and simple.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

I tried using these functions but they are not working, returning any empty list.

```
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

def find_between_r( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.rindex( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.rindex( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by finding the indexes of the words and using slices:

```
try:
    get_index = l.index('Get')
    here_index = l.index('here')
except IndexError:
    raise ValueError("Get or here is missing")

without_get = l[get_index + 1:]
without_both = l[get_index + 1:here_index]
```

Answer (score 4):

if l = ['Get', 'coffee', 'and', 'water', 'here']

then you have to do the following:

```
l2 = l[1:]
l3 = l[1:4]
```

Comment: No no, I want to grab the words based on the word and not based on the length of the list.  For example, grabbing words after 'Get'

Comment: @DasmondMiles This slices the list; it doesn't give you the length.

Comment: @DasmonMiles then you need to iterate over the elements and add elements to another list based on your criteria

Comment: @Carcigenicate: He uses `4` because the word `'here'` happens to be at that position, but the OP wants it to work without that knowledge.

Comment: @zondo Ahh, I misread his comment. You're right. This answer's first version does that though.

Comment: Providing you know "Get" is the first element.